# Cmder integration in VS Code with PowerShell not working as expected

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, cmder

I'm trying to use Cmder in VS Code for PowerShell instead of powershell.exe. I followed the official instructions ([here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration#use-powershell-instead-of-cmdexe)) on the cmder GitHub. Now, when I restart VS Code a terminal will be launched. Looks like this:

[image]

It's name is 'powershell' and it looks like Cmder but doesn't behave like it.
Perhaps I'm expecting something that is not designed to work but I was expecting 'CTRL+ Backspace' to delete words to the left. Instead I'm getting '^W':

[image]

Moreover, as soon as I open a .ps1 file a new terminal gets launched which is named 'PowerShell Integrated Console':

[image]

The behaviour of this terminal is the same as the 'powershell' one.

Here's my settings related to the integrated terminal and PowerShell in the settings.json:

```json
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-ExecutionPolicy",
        "Bypass",
        "-NoLogo",
        "-NoProfile",
        "-NoExit",
        "-Command",
        ". 'C:\\Users\\fhe\\[REMOVED]\\Apps\\cmder_mini\\vendor\\profile.ps1'"
    ],
    "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "auto",
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000,
    "powershell.scriptAnalysis.enable": true,
    "powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute": false,
    "powershell.enableProfileLoading": true,
```

I notice that if I change it back to what the official guide suggests under the 'Run Cmder as the VS Code terminal' ([here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration#vs-code-terminal)) I will get the expected behaviour when using CTRL+Backspace.

So my questions are:

1. Is Cmder integration in VS Code designed to provide the CTRL+Backspace functionality for PowerShell?
2. If so, what might I have configured incorrectly?

Thanks.